# How to call functions of next/previous object in list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how objects in a list of objects can reference the methods of the other objects in the list.

The scenario is a multi-player turn based game, where each player is an object of `class Player(object)`, and they exist in a list `players = [p1, p2, p3, etc.]`. The `Player` class already has functions to do things like `gainPoints()` and `losePoints()`, but I want players to be able to do that to either the player before them, the player after, or all other players.

I assume the first step is to create functions that determine who those players are within the `Player` class, and then `p1` could do something like `p1.losePoints(nextPlayer())` or `p1.nextPlayer().losePoints()`  to make `p2` lose points, but I have no idea how I would write the `nextPlayer()` function, or once that's done, how I would call it with `losePoints()`. Any search terms I try take me to the `itertools` documentation, which I've read but don't see how I could apply.

Since the upper bound of players is only 4, I'm sure I could find some convoluted way to solve this, but I want to learn what the right way to solve this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *nextPlayer()* method can *index* the list for *self* to find its own position.

Here's a little code to get you started:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, points=0):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
    def gain_points(self, n):
        self.points += n
    def next_player(self):
        i = players.index(self)
        return players[i+1]
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r, %r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name, self.points)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    players = [Player('Manny'), Player('Mo'), Player('Jack')]
    players[1].next_player().gain_points(5)
    print players
```

If you need the player list to "wrap-around", use a modulo in the *next_player* calculation:

```
def next_player(self):
    i = players.index(self)
    return players[(i+1) % len(players)]
```

Comment: Your initial post before the example was enough that I could get it working, but my function was `def next_player(player):` `i = players.index(player) + 1` `return players[i]` using `player` as the argument and not `self`. Are they equivalent? If so, is one better to use?

Comment: They are equivalent.  The one using "self" is the preferred python style.

Comment: This works although it's worth considering whether it represents a sensible design - now the Player class, instead of holding local Player state has to know the implementation details of global game state and has also gained the responsibility of implementing some of the games rules.

It's usually helpful to delineate things like - global game state (of which a list of Player objects is a part), the handler of player actions, the application of game rules to the global game state in response to actions, etc. Spreading these in dribbles in many places gets confusing very quickly

Comment: @pvg, I agree. It would be better that the `Player` object holds a reference to a class `Game` or something like that, and delegate there whenever more "global" state is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this is to just keep track of the index of the current player in the list. Then you can do:

```
prevIndex = currentIndex - 1
nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % len(players)
players[prevIndex].losePoints(params)
players[nextIndex].gainPoints(params)
```

This will work without scanning the list and is equally fast no matter how many entries there are in the player list. It also keeps the player list and other complications out of your player class.